# How to completely close terminal (Ubuntu bash) from TMUX session?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, tmux

Can someone please help as how can I close the bash terminal completely from inside of TMUX session (closing TMUX session as well)?

Below code is from my .bashrc where TMUX session starts as soon as terminal launches

`if command -v tmux &> /dev/null && [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then tmux attach -t default -c "$HOME" || tmux new -s default -c "$HOME" fi`

Thanks!

Comment: ...huh? There isn't such a thing as a "bash terminal" at all; bash _can_ be run with its input and output connected to a terminal, but the terminal is not part of bash (and a copy of bash run inside tmux uses tmux as its terminal, when no contrary redirection has been done). If you want to _replace_ the parent shell with a copy of tmux so it no longer exists (and won't come back when tmux exits), that's one thing (and the change you need to make is using `exec`). If you want to command tmux to exit, that's another thing. But I'm really not clear what you're asking how to do here.

Comment: Well!! Thanks for the clarification b/w Bash and Terminal. My ask is how can I exit the terminal using a single command (or shell script) from inside TMUX session.

Comment: ...okay, "the terminal" being tmux itself, or "the terminal" being a GUI program like xterm, Gnome terminal, etc. that tmux is using as _its_ terminal? There are two sides, if you want to quit both: Making sure there's no parent shell to tmux waiting to take over control when tmux exits (that's what making it `exec tmux` instead of just `tmux` will buy you); and then actually commanding tmux to exit (its documentation should tell you what the relevant commands are, and I'd probably call [unix.se] a place where the question is more on-topic than here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tmux detach -P` to both detach and send `HUP` to the parent process, which should make it exit as well.